# OpenGL ES - Is it possible to perform transformations on a VBO (scale,translate,rotate)

Tags: graphics, opengl-es

Is this something that can be done more efficiently than with a vertex array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBOs just let the driver stash your geometry in (probably) video memory rather than uploading it to the driver each frame as with vertex arrays.

`glScalef()`, `glTranslatef()`, and `glRotatef()` work the same either way.